# How to Release.apk file in Ionic Project in Visual Studio

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have tried all the necessary steps to release apk file.But always find error 
**Android packages must be signed when debugging using the Release configuration. To configure Android signing, follow instructions at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613579 pushapp2 IntelliSense**

I also add build.json file and Added my-release-key.keystore 
Could someone helpme with this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `release-signing.properties` in the `platforms/android folder` of your Project with the content:

```
target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
storePassword=...
keyPassword=...
keyAlias=...
storeFile=../../resources/android-release-key.jks
```

and add your values.

Then use the ionic cli and call

> ionic cordova build android --release